# Drupal log in block and side bars and content is disable and can not log in

Tags: theming, users, nodes

Drupal log in block and side bars and content is disable and can not log in to my drupal site locally my site is based on omega theme and content regeion is also disabled and also log in block is disabled and mysite/user does not show any input box for user name and password.. what shoult i do? plz i stuck in this problem. it's very serious.

Comment: Do you have direct access to the SQL server?

Comment: yes i have direct access to SQL server

Comment: `content` region should not be disable. Why you have disabled `content` region.

Comment: This is the problem by mistake content region is disabled?